# Reference Instance Variables in Javascript Constructor

Tags: javascript, oop, closures, anonymous-function

I'm trying to maintain state on an object by doing something like this:

```
obj = function() { 
    this.foo = undefined; 
    this.changeState = function () { 
        (function () { this.foo = "bar" })(); // This is contrived, but same idea.
    }; 
};
```

I want to set the instance variable foo to "bar" when I call the changeState method.

For instance:

```
o = new obj();
o.changeState();
alert(o.foo); // This should say "bar"
```

As far as I can tell, what is happening is that "this" in the inner anonymous function is pointing to window. I'm not sure what's going on.

Am I on the right track? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you specify a this context when calling a function the default will be the global (which in browsers is window).

Alternatives are:-

```
obj = function() { 
  this.foo = undefined; 
  this.changeState = function () { 
    (function () { this.foo = "bar" }).call(this); // This is contrived, but same idea.
  };
```

};

or:-

```
obj = function() {
  var self = this;
  this.foo = undefined; 
  this.changeState = function () { 
    (function () { self.foo = "bar" })(); // This is contrived, but same idea.
  };
```

};

Answer (score 4):

this topic comes up a lot, but it's hard to serach for since "this" is removed from SO searches.

Basically, in JavaScript, `this` always refers to the calling object, not the context object.  Since here we call o.changeState() from the global scope, `this` refers to window.

You actually don't need the inner function for the closure to work in this case - the `changeState` function itself is enough to close a lexical scope.

```
obj = function()
{
  var self = this; 
  this.foo = undefined; 
  this.changeState = function()
  {
    self.foo = "bar";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function obj() { 
    this.foo = undefined; 
    this.changeState = function () { this.foo = "bar" };
};

var o = new obj();
o.changeState();
alert(o.foo);
```

works for me. I'm not sure why you would want to use a self-invoking function just to assign a function reference, nor why you use a function expression for your constructor rather than a function declaration.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. Just needed to save a reference to the current context and use that in the inner anonymous function:

```
obj = function() { 
    this.foo = undefined; 
    var self = this; 
    this.changeState = function () { 
        (function () { self.foo = "bar" })();
    }; 
};
```